# How to non-interactively feed ssh with Time-based One-Time Password?

Tags: bash, ssh, expect, one-time-password

Some supercomputers require time-based one-time password (OTP) to login via `ssh`. I want to avoid typing the password every time and automate login/scp/rsync via bash script, in which I generate the one-time password and then pass the one-time password to ssh by using `sshpass`:

`sshpass -p my_password_and_OTP ssh user@hostname`

This `sshpass` works for usual `ssh`, but my testing indicates it does not work for `ssh` requiring one-time password. I am wondering whether there is a way to non-interactively feed ssh with Time-based One-Time Password.

Comment: Depends on implementation details not given here -- when re-asking this somewhere it's on-topic (like [unix.se]), you'll want to include the output of `ssh -vv yourhost`; the log messages will indicate how the OTP is passed (importantly, whether it's treated like an authentication step at SSH's level, or performed after the interactive session is established). If the latter, you'll need Expect-like automation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the information. I will try to investigate the implementation used in the specific machine I am trying to login (NERSC cori). I hope the implementation does not do something to make the non-interactive feeding password harder or impossible.

Comment: It's certainly not *impossible* -- worst-case, you can use [Expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect), [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [EmPTY](http://empty.sourceforge.net/), etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution using `expect`+`oathtool`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set otp [exec oathtool --totp -b my_secrete_key]
set timeout -1
spawn scp a.f90 usrname@cori.nersc.gov:~/
expect "Password + OTP:"
send -- "my_passwd${otp}\r"
expect eof
```

I use `oathtool` to generate the one-time-password and store the result in a variable `otp`.